# EFCore troubleshooting with nullable DateTime

Tags: uwp, entity-framework-core

I have an issue with EFCore and nullable DateTime in a UWP application.
I declared my property as the following in my model:

```
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

I add new entity with `Date = null`. Then I can get my entities with `Date == null` like this:

```
MyContext.MyDbSet.Where(x => x.Date == null).ToList();
```

When I launch the app in debug mode, this works well. But in release mode, this returns also entities with `Date != null`.

Comment: Have you tried with `DBNull.Value`? eg. `Where(x => x.Date == DBNull.Value)`

Comment: It does not work (compilation error). I tried checking the HasValue property but it does not work either (eg. Where(x => !x.Date.HasValue)